# Aplicação em JavaFXML com datepicker, inserir valor na BD

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, javafx

Tenho de inserir o valor de um datepicker que vem no formato DD-MM-YYYY na base de dados e quando corro a aplicação aparece-me este erro: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date" Tenho declarado assim o DatePicker e depois vai ser chamado na inserção da data a partir de um calendario

```
     @FXML
         DatePicker dataHoje;

     String SQLquery1 = "INSERT INTO Marcacao(IdMarcacao,IdUtente,IdServico,DataMarcacao)"
                            + "VALUES (" + id + "," + IdUtenteAgendar.getText() + "," + IdServicoAgendar.getText() + "," + dataHoje.getValue() + ");";
```

Comment: Voce refez a mesma pergunta que eu ja havia fechado como duplicata. Por favor, nao replique perguntas.

Comment: 1- voce precisa ter certeza de que o retorno seja realmente um tipo Date; 2- utilize preparedStatement e nao insira diretamente na query; 3- veja os links da outra duplicata, acredito que neles tem a solucao do seu problema.